# Couchbase N1QL basic select with named parameter

Tags: python, couchbase

Trying basic N1QL select (simplified version of query given by [official docs](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/start-using-sdk.html)) seems to work only with ordered parameters and does not work at least for me wit named parameters (returns empty set):

```
from couchbase.n1ql import N1QLQuery
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
bucket = Bucket('couchbase://127.0.0.1/travel-sample')

# ordered param - works
query = N1QLQuery('SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` WHERE city=$1', "London")

# named param - does not work
query = N1QLQuery('SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` WHERE city=my_city', my_city="London")

for row in bucket.n1ql_query(query):
    print(row)
```

What do I do wrong with named parameter query?

Comment: Try this. query = N1QLQuery('SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` WHERE city=$my_city', $my_city="London")

Comment: Thanks for response! This is Python, not PHP, so $my_city generates a syntax error: query = N1QLQuery('SELECT airportname, city, country FROM travel-sample WHERE city=$my_city', $my_city="London")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vsr's answer was nearly correct, your query should be:

`` query = N1QLQuery('SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` WHERE city=$my_city', my_city="London") ``

Named variables in the statement text require the $ prefix but you don't need to prefix the named parameter itself.

I'll file a documentation bug for the page you referenced to get that fixed.

Thanks.